# Copy first row of dataframe to new dataframe in a loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, append, concatenation

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\vikto\OneDrive\Skrivbord\Python\symbols2.xlsx')
mylist = df['Symbols'].tolist()

for item in mylist:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(item)
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(ticker.earnings)

    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(ticker.quarterly_earnings)
    df_2.loc['proforma'] = df_2.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
    df_2 = df_2.iloc[-1:]

    df_3 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
    df_3 = df_3.transpose()
    df_3 = df_3.loc[:, ::-1]

    df_4 = pd.DataFrame()
    df_4 = df_4.append(df_3.head(1))
```

Tried many different approaches, should be easy to just copy first row to new dataframe and keep looping?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_4 = pd.DataFrame()

for item in mylist:
  ticker = yf.Ticker(item)
  df_1 = pd.DataFrame(ticker.earnings)
  df_2 = pd.DataFrame(ticker.quarterly_earnings)
  df_2.loc['proforma'] = df_2.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
  df_2 = df_2.iloc[-1:]
  df_3 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
  df_3 = df_3.transpose()
  df_3 = df_3.loc[:, ::-1]
  df_4 = df_4.append(df_3.head(1))
```

Comment: Seems to work even though yahoo finance seems to be down. Was it as easy as i have to define df_4 outside of the for loop?